# Overflow: hidden not work

Tags: css

In image their are border that overlapped with my social icon i can't fix that
See in the pic

[image]

Border are come in background of social icons

This is my HTML

```
          <div class="social text-center">
            <p class="icons">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </p>
            <div class="divider">
          </div>
```

This is css

```
.social {
    position: relative;
}
.divider {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Please solve this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you please post your question in English so it can be understood by everyone?

Comment: Okay now u get it Lucian

Comment: it's very simple, use `z-index: -1` for `.divider`

Comment: but it stll display in background of social icons

Comment: can you show the picture of how you want it to be?

Comment: Yaa look at this link -> http://prnt.sc/eti0c6

Comment: i have answered it, please check below. also please edit the question and insert this screenshot of how you want it to so that others can understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very simple if you use `pseudo elements`

check the snippet

```css
.social {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.icons {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 10px; /* you can use this padding for the space between icons and border */
}

.icons:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

.icons:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="social text-center">
  <div class="icons">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true">123</i>
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true">123</i>
    <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true">123</i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true">123</i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true">123</i>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- remove "123" from icon -->
```

Comment: Can u can contact me on whatsapp 9737496483

Comment: Hy Lucian can u contact me ?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to contact outside of this network. If you have any problem, please ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you want to put divider but following css will put at bottom.

```
     .social {
    position: relative;
}
.divider {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.social {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.social h6 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.social h6:after,
.social h6:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 130px;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #a5a5a5;
}

.social h6:after {
    right: 95px;
    top: 12px;
}

.social h6:before {
    left: 95px;
    top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
<h6>Follow Us</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: don't use `z-index: 0` for the parent, instead use `1`. the default value of `z-index is `0` already

Comment: Yaa some good but it still display in background of social icons i have to hide this where social icon display only left and right side of social icons border is show.

Comment: then use `before` and `after` properties for it.

Comment: check my edit answer you can put your social icons instead of follow us

Comment: before and after how can i use can you tell me